# How to fix ' FCMPlugin Ready ERROR' in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm new to Phonegap.I have no prior experience with Cordova projects. I'm trying to send push notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) to app. I'm using cordova-plugin-fcm. I added google-services.json to the cordova project root. I also modified build.gradle to use the plugin. When I run the project I get the following message

```
[phonegap] [console.log] adding proxy for Device
[phonegap] [console.log] Error: exec proxy not found for :: FCMPlugin :: ready
[phonegap] [console.log] FCMPlugin Ready ERROR
[phonegap] [console.log] FCMPlugin.js: is created
[phonegap] [console.log] adding proxy for File
[phonegap] [console.log] adding proxy for Globalization
[phonegap] [console.log] adding proxy for InAppBrowser
[phonegap] [console.log] adding proxy for Capture
[phonegap] [console.log] adding proxy for NetworkStatus
[phonegap] [console.log] Persistent fs quota granted
[phonegap] [console.log] Received Event: deviceready
```

How to fix this issue? Did I miss something? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Did you get answer of this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic cordova and had the same issue. After a 5 hrs of RnD come to know that this issue was because of the ionic version installation.

**Steps to solve:**

1. Uninstall the ionic using below command

   npm uninstall -g ionic
2. Then install the below ionic version :

   npm install -g ionic@5.4.13. *(This version worked after trying many latest versions)*
3. Remove the android version

   ionic cordova platform rm android --save
4. Add new paltform

cordova platform add android@8.0.0

// After new android installation need to accept all license with below command

Go to cd. /Users/anand/Library/Android/sdk

Cd tools/bin.

Then type below command

yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses && ./sdkmanager --update

Comment: I stopped working on it a long time ago. Anyways, thanks for answering @Anand. I will leave the question here just in case someone faces the same issue.